# Getting All Objects in a Relationship Based on Name of Relationship in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

Say I have a coreData object named `Business`. `Business` have a bunch of to-many relationship.

`Business` has `Phones`, `Images`, `Districts`, `URLs`, etc.

I know can I do `NSSet somePhones = self.Phones`?

What about if I want to create a function, given the name of the relationship, namely @"Phones" will give me that same set.

So `NSSet * getManyRelationship:(NSString relationshipName)`

Can I pull that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a method in your NSManagedObject's category that looks like this:

```
- (NSSet *)getManyRelationship:(NSString *)relationshipName{
    // insert sanity checking for relationshipName form
    // needs to be camelcase:
    //     'photos' rather than 'Photos'
    //     'userPhotos' rather than 'UserPhotos' or 'userphotos'
    SEL method = NSSelectorFromString(relationshipName);
    if([workout respondsToSelector:method])
        return objc_msgSend(self, method);
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access to all attribute names by [Business attributeKeys]
and check isTooMany property for any attribute. Result will be what u need.